# Asynchronously downloading images from server using pagecontrol

Tags: ios, web-services, background-process

how to Download the set of images such that if  user scrolls each page where Page represents image download from some service asynchronously, and display the image such that i can see the number page and the current page the user in like page 1,2,3 0 IN IOS

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmattgemmell.com%2F2008%2F12%2F08%2Fwhat-have-you-tried&ei=YWcTUv2LCofRhAfOm4CYCg&usg=AFQjCNEaDvK0Yfyka3MM4mxwm1_e8khNEw&sig2=4XhJogxM-bW7ppGVut-Vtw&bvm=bv.50952593,d.ZG4) Post some code please

Comment: Hey, you should be able to this with AFNetworking. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking scroll down to the image request bit. glhf.

Answer (score 2):

For downloading and displaying multiple images in iOS you can use the [SDWebImage library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Please visit the following links too.

[SDWebImage Getting started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sdwebimage)

[Cocoa controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sdwebimage)

For pagination, you should set offset and pagenumber in the server and call the webservice using that parameters.